# Fourier Transform in $L^p$ space

Tags: analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to understand this particular step in a solution, $f \in C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$: $||\frac{\partial f}{\partial_j\partial_k}||_2^2 = C|| |\xi_j||\xi_k||\mathcal{F}f||_2^2$.

I believe they are using Plancharel and that $g(x) = -ixf(x) \implies \triangledown(\mathcal{F}f) = \mathcal{F}g$, but I do not see how this implies we can in some sense say the derivative is just some constant.

I couldn't find anything online, except a formula on Wikipedia that in general $\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n} = (\xi^n)\mathcal{F}f(\xi)$ without an explanation of why, nor where I could find why. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that is being used here is that $\mathcal F\left [ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \right ](\xi) = 2\pi i\xi_j \mathcal F[f](\xi) $.
To see where this comes from we can just use the definition of the Fourier transform (there are a few possible conventions on how to define the Fourier transform):

$$\mathcal F\left [ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \right ](\xi) = \int e^{-2\pi i x \cdot \xi}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x) dx  =-\int f(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi} dx= 2\pi i \xi_j \int f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \cdot \xi}dx = 2\pi i \xi_j \mathcal F[f](\xi) $$

(if you use another convention on how to define the Fourier transform you might even have the formula $\mathcal F\left [ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \right ](\xi) = \xi_j \mathcal F[f](\xi) $ without the factor $2 \pi i$).

Now we are using first Plancherel and then this fact twice :
$$\left \lVert \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j \partial x_k} \right \rVert_2^2 = \left \lVert \mathcal F \left [ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j \partial x_k} \right ] \right \rVert_2^2 = \left \lVert 2\pi i \xi_j\mathcal F \left [ \frac{\partial f}{ \partial x_k} \right ] \right \rVert_2^2 =\left \lVert 2\pi i \xi_j \cdot 2 \pi i \xi_k \mathcal F[f] \right \rVert_2^2 = C \lVert \xi_j \xi_k \mathcal F[f]\rVert_2^2$$

as claimed with $C= 4 \pi^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How did you do this step $\int e^{-2\pi i x \cdot \xi}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x) dx  =-\int f(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi} dx$? It looks like integration by parts, but if so I don't entirely see how.

Comment: Yes, it is integration by parts - the boundary term doesn't appear because we assumed $f \in C^2_c(\mathbb R^n)$, so it has compact support which makes the boundary terms disappear and the integral we are evaluating is really only an integral on the compact support of $f$ rather than on the whole $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Okay that already makes more sense. Does $\mathcal F\left [ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \right ](\xi) = 2\pi i\xi_j \mathcal F[f](\xi)$ only hold when $f \in C_c^2(\mathbb{R^n})$? Seeing as we used it has compact support to ignore the boundary term.

Comment: The formula for the Fourier transform of a derivative is definitely true for all functions $f \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, the Schwartz space of $C^\infty$-functions that decay faster than any polynomials and whose derivatives also decay faster than any polynomial. Compact support is an even stronger assumption. But of course we don't really need all derivatives to exist - in our example $C^2_c(\R^n)$ was enough and probably the result is true for any $C^2$-function with "very rapid" decay.